# CMake Android cross-compiling get empty compiler flags for Debug and Release

Tags: android, cmake, android-ndk

To demonstrate this issue, I made a minimum CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)
project(FlagsTest)

add_executable(myapp myapp.cpp)
```

I configure this cmake project with toolchain file inside Android NDK. Ninja generator is used, and cmake cached variable `ANDROID_ABI` is set to `armeabi-v7a`. The versions of software and toolchain are:

- CMake: 3.12.3 and 3.14.6 in Windows.
- Android NDK and toolchain file: `C:/Users/my_name/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk/20.0.5594570/build/cmake/android.toolchain.cmake`
- ninja: 1.9.0

The whole stuff successfully configured and generated. However, cmake cache variables `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG`, `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE`, `CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG` and `CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE` are **all blank**. This caused in no debug symbol in debug build, and no optimization in release build, which bothered us for a lot.

At current, I made a workaround by manually specify these variables from cmake command line. But as these variables should be automatically set by cmake, I'm wondering whether it is a bug in cmake, or a bug in Android SDK.

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by incorrect configuration in the ndk toolchain file. It set empty initial value for `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG` and `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE` that prevents CMake using the default value:

```
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG ""
  CACHE STRING "Flags used by the compiler during debug builds.")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG ""
  CACHE STRING "Flags used by the compiler during debug builds.")
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE ""
  CACHE STRING "Flags used by the compiler during release builds.")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE ""
  CACHE STRING "Flags used by the compiler during release builds.")
```

As it's not good to modify this file directly, it seems the only way to solve it is to specify the value explicitly in command-line for every first generation.

Answer (score -1):

**CMake** will take care of release and debug flags internally, you are expected to pass `-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release` or `-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug` on command line.